# getting nested value by using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

```js
let data =
 [
    {
        "testingNewValue": {
            "en-US": "hello"
        }
    },
    {
        "testingNewValue": {
            "hi-IN": "hello "
        }
    },
    {
        "testingNewValue": {
            "us": "dummy"
        }
    },
    {
        "testingNewValue": {
            "xp-op-as": "value for testing"
        },
        "locationField": {
            "en-US": {
                "lat": 19.28563,
                "lon": 72.8691
            }
        }
    }
]

const value = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(el=>(el[1]=Object.values(el[1])[0], el)))
    console.log(value);
```

I am trying to get value from the data json by using the object.fromEntries n object.entries but its not working as my expectation as I am expecting the value as

### Expectation

```
{
  {
    testingNewValue:"hello"
  },
  {
    testingNewValue:"hello"
  },
  {
    testingNewValue:"dummy"
  },
  {
    testingNewValue:"value for testing",
    locationField:{
      lat: 19.28563,
      lon: 72.8691
    }
  }
}
```

but I am getting "0","1","2" as you can see in code snippet as I want to remove  all "en-US","hi-In" n all from data

How can I get my expectation

Comment: Your expected result isn't valid, an object `{}` must have a key for each value. Did you mean to use an array `[]` for the outer brackets?

Comment: Hi @NickParsons I have updated my question I want to remove all `en-Us hi-In` and get the value as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you're actually after an array (as your current expected result isn't a valid structure), you should be taking the entires of each inner objects and then taking building your new object with `fromEntries()` after mapping each entry, rather then taking the entires of your entire `data` array which is causing the indexes to appear in your current result. The below code assumes you have one value within each inner object, and that each value is an object:

```js
const data = [ { "testingNewValue": { "en-US": "hello" } }, { "testingNewValue": { "hi-IN": "hello " } }, { "testingNewValue": { "us": "dummy" } }, { "testingNewValue": { "xp-op-as": "value for testing" }, "locationField": { "en-US": { "lat": 19.28563, "lon": 72.8691 } } } ];

const value = data.map(el=>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(el).map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.values(v)[0]]))
);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Hi Nick can I get value start with `{ }` instead of square brackets `[ ]` is this possible? as I was expecting the output in `{ }`

Comment: @Aakash no, that isn't possible. If you have `{}` then you have an object, and if you have an object, then you must have key-values within it, such as: `{key: value}`. Your expected result doesn't have any keys in it, so your expected result isn't valid. If you update your expected result to have unique keys with values, then it is possible

Comment: ya i got it @Nick but as you can see while running the code snippet my data containing `[ ]` and after running the wrong code I got `{ }`  as I was expecting the same `{ }` that's why I asked 

Comment: @Aakash Your code outputs an object, that's why it's in `{ }`, you can see that it has key-value pairs in it, for example, `"0"` is a key, and the value is `{"en-US": "hello"}`, so that's a valid structure, but in your expected result, you don't mention any keys, so it doesn't make sense to store this data in an object `{ }`, so that is why an array `[ ]` needs to be used. eg: try and store a simplified version of your expected output in a variable by manually writing it `const x = {{testingNewValue:"hello"}}`, you'll see that you get a SyntaxError as it's not valid to have this structure.